# "The Link You Followed Has Expired" error when saving a post (randomly)

Tags: errors

We are regularly (and randomly) getting "The Link You Followed Has Expired" errors when we save posts from the admin. If we go back to the post and try again to save, it works fine.

Google tells me it happens when a user tries to upload big files, but this is not the case: it happens on different custom post types, none of them having upload boxes.

However:

- On these custom posts, there are a LOT of custom fields (hundreds) - which could be the cause the error somehow.
- More likely, this is caused by one of my functions: I developed a plugin for our internal use that has multiple PHP and JS admin functions, but since the error seems to be happen randomly (maybe once every 100 saves, in all kind of situations) and almost never to me (administrator), it is hard to reproduce it in order to investigate it.

I would really appreciate if anybody could point me in the right direction, tell me where to start looking because it is becoming very problematic.

When it happens I see a 403 error in the logs, but that doesn't help me much.

This is on a multisite installation by the way.

Comment: If it's happening internally to different users it may even be the network and unrelated to WP itself.  Are all the users at the same location?  It could also be that if multiple users are loading those pages/saving those pages with hundreds of custom fields at the same time your server may just be running out of resources.  This sounds like it's hosting related because a coding error would be more predictable and easier to replicate.

Comment: Are you spending a lot of time editing the post before saving it? Or leaving the editor open for a long time before saving? A lot being something on the order of several hours.

Comment: @TonyDjukic thanks for your input. I started looking into the hosting side of things.

Comment: @JacobPeattie no, this happens even when we've been editing the post for 2 minutes.